# Agrupación de datos con filtro del más alto en un campo MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta, 
Estoy tratando de sacar la agrupación de unos campos pero que me traiga el registro con el index más alto. Este es mi [Fiddle de ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4985e4/7)

Intenté con

```
SELECT F.* FROM FOLIOS F
GROUP BY FOLIO
```

Pero esto me trae la tupla con el Id 1, Index 1 del folio 10, y estoy buscando la tupla con el Id 2, index 2 del folio 10 como "representante de la agrupación".

También intenté

```
SELECT F.* FROM FOLIOS F WHERE MAX(F.FOLIO)
GROUP BY FOLIO;
SELECT F.* FROM FOLIOS F
GROUP BY FOLIO HAVING MAX(F.FOLIO);
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado.

También me puede ayudar si la fecha es la más reciente

Me pueden apoyar con la duda?

Comment: Cual es la estructura de la tabla?

Comment: Está en el Fiddle

Comment: me queda duda en una parte de tu pregunta dices que quieres te retorne el índice mas alto que es 4 y en otra parte dices querer el 2, cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: El index más alto del grupo, por ejemplo, el grupo del folio 10, tiene 2 indices, el 10 y el 20, necesito tal cual la tupla que tiene el index 20

Answer (score 2):

Intentalo de esta manera:

```
SELECT F.* FROM FOLIOS F 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(`index`) AS max_index FROM FOLIOS GROUP BY FOLIO) max
  ON F.index = max.max_index
```

Comment: yo lo probé y otorga el resultado esperado

Comment: Gracias, a pesar que si funciona me retorna el index más alto pero la primera tupla no la tupla que corresponde al index más alto. Ya modifiqué la pregunta para ser más específico

Comment: Ya modifique mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso si deseas obtener el registro con el indice mas alto:

```
SELECT F.* FROM FOLIOS f GROUP BY FOLIO ORDER BY f.index desc limit 1
```

En el caso que necesites la fecha mas reciente:

```
SELECT F.* FROM FOLIOS f GROUP BY FOLIO ORDER BY f.date desc limit 1
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM FOLIOS t1
  LEFT JOIN FOLIOS t2
      ON t1.folio = t2.folio AND t1.id < t2.id
WHERE t2.id is NULL;
```

La consulta está inspirada en lo que se conoce como *SQL anti-paterns*  (anti-patrones de SQL).

Este tipo de prácticas tiene una amplia aceptación en el homólogo inglés de Stackoverflow, [como se puede ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/5587982) y según [comentarios en aquella respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results/28090544#comment47262083_28090544), esta consulta es 50 veces más rápida que un `JOIN ... MAX` en una tabla con 20 millones de registros... cuestión de probar.

Dejo la respuesta como otra alternativa de solución.